# How to configure IP restrict access with apiKey in API MANAGER behind a load balancer?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have configured "restrict IP" access when generating an `apiKey` to consume an API in Developer Portal API Manager 3.2, however, the IP is not client IP, it is load balancer IP.

Should I set any mediation policy in API Manager or in load balancer to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set X-Forwarded-For header which is the user IP at the load balancer. Then this is used by the API Manager to do the validation.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/